# ReactJS: Unable to grab data from a function

Tags: javascript, reactjs, function

I am currently having trouble accessing a value within a function but this is OUTSIDE OF A PROMISE.

Here is my code:

```
 service.getDistanceMatrix({
        origins: ["Waterloo ON"],
        destinations: destination,
        travelMode: 'DRIVING',
        avoidHighways: false,
        avoidTolls: false
      }, function(response, status){
       if (status == 'OK') {
         var origins = response.originAddresses;
         var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

         for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
           var results = response.rows[i].elements;
           for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
             var element = results[j];
             var distance = element.distance.text;
             var duration = element.duration.text;
             var from = origins[i];
             var to = destinations[j];
             // _this.
             // console.log(distance);
             location.distFinal = distance;

             location.setState({
               dist: distance
             })
             // return distance;
             // return distance;
             // console.dir(distance)
             // tryA = distance;
           }
         }

       }
     })
     console.dir(location);
     console.dir(location.distFinal);
```

I am trying to access the distance so I did console.dir(location.distFinal) but it gave me an undefined value. However, when I did console.dir(location), it gave me the object with distFinal as a value....

This is what I mean:

[image]

Line 126 is the console.dir(location) and line 127is console.dir(location.distFinal)

Please! I just want to be able to extract the distance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not in a promise currently, so try converting it *into* a promise - that way you can resolve once the asynchronous code has the data you want. Then you can `.then` on the promise to run code after it's resolved.

```js
//  location is defined somewhere up here
new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  service.getDistanceMatrix({
    origins: ["Waterloo ON"],
    destinations: destination,
    travelMode: 'DRIVING',
    avoidHighways: false,
    avoidTolls: false
  }, function(response, status){
    if (status == 'OK') {
      var origins = response.originAddresses;
      var destinations = response.destinationAddresses;

      for (var i = 0; i < origins.length; i++) {
        var results = response.rows[i].elements;
        for (var j = 0; j < results.length; j++) {
          var element = results[j];
          var distance = element.distance.text;
          var duration = element.duration.text;
          var from = origins[i];
          var to = destinations[j];
          // _this.
          // console.log(distance);
          location.distFinal = distance;

          location.setState({
            dist: distance
          })
          // return distance;
          // return distance;
          // console.dir(distance)
          // tryA = distance;
        }
      }
      // looping is done
      resolve();
    }
  })
}).then(() => {
  console.dir(location);
  console.dir(location.distFinal);
});
```

The reason you can `console.dir` is because Chrome's console requests the state of the object *when you open* the console, rather than displaying the state of the object *as it was*.

Comment: I can't seem to get the value out of the .then() function

Comment: If you want `then` to resolve with a value, then pass that value into the `resolve` function. For example `resolve(someVar)` and then you could do `.then(someVar => { /* interact with someVar */ })`. Here, you might be looking to resolve with an array of `distance`s or something?

Comment: Thank you, that worked but how do I get it out of the promise? Like res is now a value but I want to get that specific value out of the promise/then function

Comment: If you want to access it on the higher level, you'll have to use `await`, and you'll have to be in an async function. Eg `const resolveValue = await new Promise(resolve ... ... ... resolve(resolveValue) ...`